# How can i make patterns using do while loops in C#

Tags: c#, do-while, do-loops

I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to looping. :( 
please help me.

Question:

> Using a `do` loop, draw the following pattern:

```
*   
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: This looks like a school assignment, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: just try it with 2 nested do-loops, do not wait for answers.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: This is very easy .. I actually did this exact thing using the AddRange() method hint.. do a google search on how to use it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 1;

        do {

            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); // for newline
            counter++;   // increase counter

        } while (counter < 6);
    }
}
```

sorry for my bad english.
You can use a counter in the do-while loop

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that generates stars string:

```
public static string starGenerator(int count)
{
    string stars = string.Empty;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        stars += "*";

    return stars;
}
```

And then use it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 1;
    do
    {
        string stars = starGenerator(counter);
        Console.WriteLine(stars);

        counter++;
    } while(counter <= 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement this, if you insist on `do..while`:

```
string line = "";

do {
  Console.WriteLine(line += "*");
}
while (line.Length < 6);
```